# "But it's good to know it's there a possibility."

Tags: grammar, word-order

I am thinking about what it correct in the sentence above:

...it's there a possibility
or
...there is a possibility.

The original version sound a bit unnatural for me. Please, help me.

Comment: _It's there a possibility_ doesn't make sense; it must be an error.

Comment: Are you possibly missing the word 'as' - "it's there as a possibility' is a phrase in my variety of regional English. e.g. A: "Did you still need a car? My friend Steve is selling his..", B: "I've found one I'm interested in, but it's good to know it's there as a possibility" [e.g. if the other sale falls through]

Answer (score 1):

"It's" is a contraction of "It is". *It is there a possibility* is a grammatical nonsense.

*There is a possibility* is a statement of fact; *a possibility exists.*

"Is there a possibility" would be a question.

---

> But it's good to know there is a possibility.

The statement of direct dependency: if there is a possibility, knowing that it is, is good. Knowing there is no possibility is probably bad; so is not knowing.

Oppose to:

> "But it's good to know: is there a possibility?"

or

> "But it's good to know whether there is a possibility."

In this case knowing is the good thing. It's good to know there is possibility, and it's good to know there's no possibility. It's only bad not to know either way.

---

And then there's one more viable form:

> "But it's good to know it's a possibility."

> "But it's good to know it's a possibility there."

Statement of fact: [something] is possible [optionally: somewhere, in some context] and knowing this fact is a good thing.

> "But it's good to know if it's a possibility [there]."

It's not known whether something is possible or not, but gaining that knowledge is valuable.